# Como fazer uma rotina de envio determinados dados de um banco MySQL para outro

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Sou iniciante e entusiasta em programação web.

Eu tentando desenvolver um sistema que funciona basicamente assim:
Eu tenho um registro de contatos, só que funcionando em localhost (PHP e MySQL) - porque preciso de um sistema que funcione mesmo quando a máquina por algum acaso esteja sem internet.

Pensei em fazer uma rotina que funcione, por exemplo, a cada 10min e que envie somente os dados novos para um outro banco de dados (meio que repassar para uma DB MySQL em um webhost mesmo). Só que para evitar o conflito de dados (ex.: id da coluna), ele enviasse as variáveis para um form em PHP que repassaria esses dados para o segundo banco MySQL.

Eu consegui achar meios que funcionassem pra enviar o banco de dados MySQL por e-mail, mas nada que fosse para um outro host.

Conseguiria fazer isso usando PHP, vi algo sobre Cron Job. Alguém tem algum norte do que eu deveria pesquisar e estudar estritamente pra desenvolver esse código?

Comment: Se eu entendi bem você quer salvar seus dados em um servidor remoto, você pode usar JS para isso.

Comment: Basicamente sim, o que não pode ocorrer é a duplicata de dados e nem depender de que o browser esteja aberto, ou seja, se agora foi enviado algo, daqui a 10min ele pega o conteúdo e insere no outro banco de dados, caso contrário nada é feito e a rotina se repete (a cada 10min). Quando algo novo for inserido e a rotina rodar novamente, esse dado novo será enviado para o outro banco (somente esse dado novo).

Comment: Vai ter que usar `Cron` mesmo

Comment: Qual o nome do que tenho que estudar no caso pra isso? É algo específico em Cron? No caso eu teria que fazer duas rotinas no meu script né: Uma para verificar se há dados novos e outra pra fazer o envio, das novas, certo?

Comment: O próprio mysql possui um sistema bem robusto de replicação master/slave. E o mais legal é que ele funciona de forma transparente. Você já pesquisou a respeito?

Comment: Nunca havia ouvido falar em, mas agora que sugeriu vou dar uma pesquisada sobre então!